# Registration on php went wrong

Tags: php

I am a newbie in php, so I am learning the basics...

HTML:

```
<form action="reg.php" method="post">

                                <input name="realname" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Имя" class="input-style b2 w1-ha db left m-b5"/>
                                <input name="login" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Логин" class="input-style b2 w1-ha db left m-b5" />
                                <input name="password" type="password" size="15" maxlength="15" placeholder="Пароль" class="input-style b2 w1-ha db left m-b5" />

                                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="left m-t10 btn green-btn">Зарегистрироваться</button>

                            </form>
```

Here is the PHP code of the registration on the webpage:

```
<?php

include_once('other/inc/config.php');
include_once('other/inc/bd.php');

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {  
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    if ($login == '') {
        unset($login);
    } 
} 

if (isset($_POST['password'])) {  
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if ($password == '') {
        unset($password);
    } 
}
if (isset($_POST['realname'])) {  
    $name = $_POST['realname'];
    if ($name == '') {
        unset($name);
    } 
}

//заносим введенный пользователем пароль в переменную $password, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
if (empty($login) or empty($password) or empty($name)) { //если пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем ошибку и останавливаем скрипт
    scriptT('You did not enter the whole information');
  header('Refresh: 0; URL= /');
}
//если логин и пароль введены, то обрабатываем их, чтобы теги и скрипты не работали, мало ли что люди могут ввести

$name = checkTxtI($name);
$login = checkTxtI($login);

$password = checkPass($password);

// проверка на существование пользователя с таким же логином
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = '$login'", $db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!empty($myrow['id'])) {
    scriptT('Sorry, this login is already taken. Please enter another one.);
  header('Refresh: 0; URL= /');
}

// если такого нет, то сохраняем данные
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (realname, login, password) VALUES('$name', '$login', '$password')") or die(mysql_error());

if($result2 = 'TRUE') {
  scriptT('You have registered!!');
  header('Refresh: 0; URL= /');
} else {
  scriptT('Error!');
  header('Refresh: 0; URL= /');
}
?>
```

Where is the error? I always get error that I did not enter some of the fields in the form, but actually I did.

Please help me :)

Comment: `$result2 = 'TRUE'` is the immediate red flag and wrong in several ways. Please post the HTML of the form as well, and perhaps point out which one of the error messages is triggered (most of us don't speak Russian).

Comment: Can you indicate the error message you are getting, for us English speakers.

Comment: I updated the code above, not it is all in English!

Comment: You still need to add the form HTML.

Comment: Just added HTML, it is not because of HTML for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- in PHP nothing called **or**  use **||** instead in your if statement
- Always check your code in each step
- Try using **mysqli** or **pdo** with database instead of **mysql** to be sure it will work with
  the newer PHP Version

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i know the most of it. I am doing this is because I want to take the basics of PHP and then start to write on something more efficient. What is the error in my code? I am receiving the empty fields in mysql.

Comment: Ok. check all your query in your phpMyadmin first and in PHP some basics in if statement you should to (=== TRUE) or (== 'string') just one equal in if statement not work

Comment: I did what you asked. I checked queries in mysql and I updated my code as you suggested but nothing changed. Right now, after I press "Register", I receive two different errors in the row (one after another) 1. You login is already taken. (It is not true, actually the login that I tried to register doesn't exit in the db) 2. You are registered. After this, it send the information to the db with empty fields :(

Comment: run mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (realname, login, password) VALUES('username', 'loginfield', 'password')") or die(mysql_error()); in your php and check that everything goes right

Comment: It went right! I have these values in my bd now :) 
What should I do next?

Comment: I receive all of the errors because it has my name values empty, but I have no idea why...

Comment: use mysql_fetch_row to get $row['id'] instead of mysql_fetch_array you get data with array by $row[0] and better of that if you want to check if user exists. just use a mysql_num_rows where username = 'username'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65005/discussion-between-user3661795-and-mohamed-yousef).

Comment: if(mysql_num_rows("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login = '$login'", $db) == 1){ echo 'user exists';}